# Exceptions as a control mechanism

Tags: exception, language-design

I was reading this post and laughed http://mcfunley.com/239/exceptions-are-not-a-control-mechanism

In one of my apps i do not use File.Exist even tho i EXPECT files to exist a good deal of the time. I try to create a file without overwriting the older and if it fails i rename as Filename (Try Number).ext and loop until it opens.

Should i used File.Exist in this case ? or should i continue to try opening a file, loop until i do then write pattern?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion exceptions should generally be reserved for truely exceptional circumstances for several reasons:

1. Exceptions have a high performance overhead (though that might not really a problem when e.g. dealing with files)
2. Having an application throing and swallowing a high amount of exceptions can make debugging very hard

   - You might swallow the exception you are looking for somewhere
   - It can make it kind of hard for others to follow the programmflow, exspecially if the exceptions are catched higher in the call-hierarchie

Of course in your specific case it might make sense to rely on the exceptions since checking `File.Exitsts()` beforehand doesn't guarantee that the file exists when it is accessed, so you might have to include the exceptional case anyhow

Answer (score 1):

This question is known as LBYL vs. EAFP: *Look Before You Leap* vs. *It's Easier to Ask Forgiveness Than Permission*. There are [many disussions of this topic here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=lbyl+eafp).

Answer (score 1):

I'd leave the whole "exceptions for exceptional situation" thing aside for now and simply analyse your situation in order to persuade you that it is correct and you should only use exceptions for exceptional situations.

In your case you seemingly do

```
while (!opened) { 
   try {
       <file_open>;
       opened = true
   } catch (exception) {
       //ignore
   }
}
```

You'd end up eating all CPU time very easy. If you do

```
while (!opened) { 
   if (file.exists) {
       <file_open>
       opened = true
   } else {
       Thread.sleep(<some_time>);
   }
}
```

You would be playing nice, giving your unused time to other processes and keep the CPU to a minimum

So in my opinion, I'd say that it would be a very good idea to test first.

Comment: actually i am giving the file a different name if its used and also the files should not be deleted so wait for it to be writable will never happen until a user decided to back it up and move it into another folde

Comment: OK, sorry about the mistake. I don't really understand what you do when waiting for a file to become "writable".

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend checking File.Exist, the exception path can be very performance costly otherwise.

Comment: Performance isn't always an issue with exceptions, depends on the language and O/S. Also opening a file is likely to be in a non critical part of code..

Comment: OK, i aggree, but i find myself to be a defensive programmer. Rather believe that the user of my code is not quite sure what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are for exceptional situations.

All you need is a test; there is nothing exceptional about that, so use if File.Exist.