# How can I know if I cannot convert a string into a object using TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString

Tags: c#, typedescriptor

I'm using `TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString` in order to convert strings into concrete types.

Some conversions fail via and exception, and I would like to know about the failure before trying to convert.

Code example that will fail:

```
var tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(int));
var val = tc.ConvertFromInvariantString("1.5");
```

Code that I'd wan't to have:

```
var canConvert = CanConvert(tc, "1.5", typeof(int));
if(canConvert)
{
   var val = tc.ConvertFromInvariantString("1.5");
   ......
}
```

I prefer not to use a try\catch block as a solution as I wan't to get a list of properties prior to the operation.

I've noticed the `CanConvertFrom` method that doesn't really work (It returns false when converting a float to double while the `TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString` method succeeds).

So, is there a way to determine if I can convert the string into the type prior to the conversion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4492344 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1308432

Comment: @Plutonix - Thanks for the ref. Didn't notice the small impact. Will update the post and remove that.